# Concorde thrust reversers engaged on parked aircraft, but not all engines?

Tags: airliner, supersonic, thrust-reverser, concorde, nacelle

[image]

Am I correct in interpreting this photo as showing one thrust reverser engaged, while the other is open? Do the thrust reversers fall into place on a fully powered down Concorde? Could this be caused by an engine being removed for display? If so which engine was removed?

Comment: They might have opened it just for display purposes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes the left (#1) reverser is engaged in this photo. [G-AXDN](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/g-axdn-101) is the British pre-production Concorde and has some differences from the final versions. [G-AXDN](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/g-axdn-101) contained internal clam shell reversers, [if the GIF at the bottom of this informational page about G-AXDN is any indicator that external engine reverser may still actuate for show](https://www.heritageconcorde.com/duxford) and in this case was simply closed while you were there. This video shows the [light up ring that they may have used in the GIF (5:02)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfHEevrtog0)

[This Concorde also has a droop nose](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-cambridgeshire-29755140) that still [works.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm0fMXxRrm0) There is also a [fairly active effort going on](https://www.youtube.com/user/HeritageConcorde/videos) to restore that airframe to have some of the parts work.